# AWS CloudWatch Web Server Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a few EC2 instances with NGINX installed using both ports 80 and 443.  The instances are serving different applications so I'm not using an ELB.

I would like to create a CloudWatch alarm to make sure port 80 is always returning 200 HTTP status code.  I realize there are several commercial solutions for this such as New Relic, etc, but this is the task I have at hand at the moment.

None of the EC2 metrics look to be able to accomplish this, and I cannot use any ELB metrics since I have no ELB.

What's the  best way to resolve this?

Comment: the do this with http://www.monitor.us/

Answer (score 0):

You can definetly do this manually (send a request and update a metric directly sent to Cloudwatch). Monitor that metric.

Or you could look into Route53 health checks. You might get away with just configuring a health check there if you are already using Route53:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a Route53 [Heath Check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-monitor-view-status.html). Supported protocols are TCP, HTTP, and HTTPS.

The HTTP/S protocol supports matching the response payload against a user-defined string so you can not only react to connectivity problems but also to unexpected content being returned to users.

For a more advanced monitoring enable Latency metrics which collect TTFB (time to first byte) and SSL handshake times.

You can then create alarms to get alerts when one your apps becomes inaccessible.

[image: route 53 health check]